# PHP strtotime date today, which is better?

Tags: php

I was wondering if one method is better than the other when it comes to getting the timestamp of the date today.

Which is better?

```
$timestamp = strtotime("now");
```

or

```
$date_today = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$timestamp = strtotime($date_today);
```

Is there even a difference?

Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Neither. You should use [time()](http://php.net/time).

Answer (score 4):

They're both sub-optimal (but trivially so in almost every case).

Try:

```
<?PHP
$timestamp = time();
```